# trouble with bring a remote cakephp site to local MAMP OS X

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, operating-system, mamp

First, I am a total newbie.  A developer created a cakephp app that works great on amazon web services.  I need to get the app working locally so that I can make minor edits etc.  I actually had the thing working after tons of work but tried to get a newer version going by dragging and dropping the new files in.  Now, I only get blank screen.  I have been messing with many files such as .htaccess with no success.  I probably will try to start from scratch but wanted to ask what the very fundamental steps are to do this.  For example, I do I need to cakebake prior to transferring the files are after transferring. Do I need to make any connections  using terminal or  will my software already have this inherent in it;Do I need to remove any files in other files if I start clean.  I am really at a loss at this point and want to at least make sure that i am not missing anything obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If pulling this from production, then it might be wise to change the debug level in core.php config file. Please see [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration). In production, you usually change this to the lowest setting, however in development you'd wanna put this up to at least 2 to help get to the root of whitescreens.

Answer (score 0):

Change the debug level in app/Config/core.php. Set it to 2 instead of 0. There will be sometime when in production mode (0), whitescreen will occur as errors will not be shown on screen.

Also, based on my observation,looks like you are pretty new to CakePHP and have no basic understanding. Don't get me wrong. But it always nice to learn new things.

Heads up to http://cakephp.org to learn at least the basics.